# spring security 6 custom filter errors with 403 forbidden

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

When trying to test custom authentication using a custom filter (using spring security 6); I keep receiving "Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access" error in DEBUG logs. Does anyone know what I am missing in the configuration.
I left the filter code empty for now.

This is what I see in DB logs when I hit the endpoint:

```
14:23:02.619 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 1 ms
14:23:04.923 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /hello
14:23:04.928 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
14:23:04.943 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - Saved request http://localhost:8080/hello?continue to session
14:23:04.943 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
14:23:05.504 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /error
14:23:05.505 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
14:23:05.505 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - Saved request http://localhost:8080/error?continue to session
14:23:05.505 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
{
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class TestFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(
            ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.print("::::::::::::::::::::in the test filter::::::::::::::::::::::");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would expect anything other than a 403?  If you want to call the `/hello` endpoint without being authenticated, then you need to add that to your security filter chain as a `permitAll()`

Comment: This is just a test filter where I am trying to prove spring security works. I have another project where I want to apply these learnings...in which my actual filter does inspect the header for a cookie and validate against the database.

Comment: @KishorePaila Spring Security works perfectly. You are not authenticated, so you can't access any resource. Your code works as it should be. If you expect something else, you should add athentication to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, despite attempt to authenticate all Http requests, probably framework is expecting few more configuration. Due to lack of those configuration it is probably triggering forbidden access.

Could you try something as below and let us know if it works?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(new TestFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

we configure an in-memory user store with a single user "user" having the password "password" and the role "USER". The configure(HttpSecurity http) method defines the authorization rules, allowing any request to be authenticated and using HTTP Basic authentication, obviously you can further enhance as per your need. I assume, missing credentials were triggering that error (just a guess).

Answer (score -1):

The only way I could tell Spring to only execute my filter (once) and not do anything else is with this configuration:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: My filter executed and I received a "200 OK" with this configuration.